# What would be the upper and lower limit of this?

Tags: polar-coordinates

> Find the area of the region inside the circle $r=-4 \sin(θ)$ and outside the circle $r=2$

I equated both the equations which gave me sin(θ)= -1/2. Then, i drew both the circles roughly on an x-y plane. Both the circles intercept at angles -π/6 and -5π/6 which are ultimately the limits which will be used in the formula. Now, the problem comes here. I am not sure what would be the upper and lower limit out of these two.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? And what would be a more conventional way to describe the first circle?

Comment: @AlexamderGeldhof I guess the first obstacle is to show that the first region is actually a circle. That's not immediately obvious, at least to me.